# Increase a value each time a cell is returned

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I increase a value just after I return a cell in my tableView ?

```
var indexDigit1 = 0
var indexDigit2 = 1

cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(array[indexDigit1])"+"\(array[indexDigit2])"

indexDigit1 = indexDigit1 + 2
indexDigit2 = indexDigit2 + 2

return cell
```

But I'd like that indexDigit1 and indexDigit2 change for every cell in my tableView.

So for example : indexDigit1 should be 2 and indexDigit2 should be 3 for the second cell, 4 and 5 for the third etc.. So the value in the label can change !

Comment: Your approach looks already wrong. Note that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can be called for the rows in arbitrary order, repeatedly, ... That's why that method has an `indexPath` parameter!

Comment: You should try it with more rows than fit on the screen, and then scroll up and down.

Answer (score 2):

Where is this code living? Seems like if you want indexDigit1 to be (+1) of the row index (second cell would be indexPath.row == 1), and indexDigit2 to be (+2) of the row index, you don't even need a variable, and you want just use `cellForItem`'s `indexPath.row` property.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need, you can create an array that its position (index) will represent the value you need which in your case indexDigit1 is the position and the value is 0.

*For example:*

Let's say your table has only 10 cells, thus:

```
array = [Int](count: 10, repeatedValue: 0)
```

For the technical part you will use the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and assign the value you need for the `indexPath.row` you need:

```
array[indexPath.row] = theValueYouNeed
```

Also, looks like maybe you need some sort of formula for the value, maybe `theValueYouNeed += 2` or something more complicated that will suit your need.

Now, you can extract the value you need for each `indexPath.row`:

```
let theValueYouNeedForTheCorrespondingRow = array[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: `[Int](arrayLiteral: 10)` returns an array with the *single* element `10`, not a 10-element array. Actually I don't know any case where you would need to use the `arrayLiteral` (or any other `xxxLiteral` constructor  in your code.